# Could not load file or assembly but they are loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-assembly, filenotfoundexception, appdomain

I have a project going on witch uses a DLL from an ERP system.
The DLL is used to get information from the ERP, like invoices and such. 
The error i am getting is:

> Inner Exception 1: FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'SnelStartGatewayInterface, Version=12.48.37.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

But in the same window I used 'watch 1' to see the current using assembly's with the method:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
```

It returns a couple of assembly's.
This is the one loaded in and exactly the same as seen in the error:

> +        [36]    {SnelStartGatewayInterface, Version=12.48.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null}   System.Reflection.Assembly
>   {System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly}

Why would it return me the error?

Ps. I have tried the exact same method and dll in a windows forms test app and it was running fine.

Comment: take a look at "...or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified." it might be the dependency loading that failed.

Comment: I am kinda new to programming and haven't worked with Dll's. Could you give me help and tell me where i could find the dependencies or help me te see the dependencies that are loaded.

Comment: @Naaman look at my answer. There is example code to get all referenced assemblies.

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is it you are *really* trying to accomplish? Normally, for *managed* assemblies, you set a reference before compiling them, you don't load them using Reflection. Is this some sort of deployment issue? Is the ERP system DLL even written in .NET?

Answer (score 0):

Like Pawl Lukasik mentioned in the comments, you should look at the dependencies.

To do this, use:

```
private List<string> ListReferencedAssemblies()
{
    List<string> refList = new List<string>();
    var assemblies = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies();
    foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
    {
        refList.Add(assembly.Name);
    }

    return refList;
}
```

to see all referenced assemblies.

Or with LINQ:

```
private List<string> ListReferencedAssemblies()
{
    return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies().Select(x => x.FullName).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I have tried the code you provided but the problem is that the current executing assembly isn't the one mentioned in the error.